# Equivalent properties of projective modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

> For a left $R$ module $P$, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. Given $M\xrightarrow{\psi} N \to 0$ exact and $\omega: P \to N$,
>      there exists $\tilde{\omega}: P \to M$ such that $\psi \circ
>         \tilde{\omega} = \omega$.
> 2. Every short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B
>             \to P \to 0$ splits.
> 3. $P$ is a direct summand of a free module.

In proving this equivalence, we typically go $1 \implies 2 \implies 3 \implies 1$. I'm interested in more direct proofs of $3 \implies 2$ and $2 \implies 1$. Does anyone know any?

**Update:** I think I showed $3 \implies 2$...I'll post it.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155248/characterization-of-projective-and-injective-modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $2 \Rightarrow 1$ the pullback $M \times_N P \to P$ of a surjective map is surjective so by $(2)$ it splits and we have maps $P \to M \times_N P \to M$.  Check that these define $\tilde\omega$ as desired.

For $3 \Rightarrow 2$ take $S$ such that $P \oplus S$ is free.  Then there is a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \oplus S \to P \oplus S \to 0$ which splits because $P \oplus S$ has a basis.  Show that the splitting maps $P$ into $B$ and that this restriction splits the original short exact sequence.