# Under what circumstances are the relative Kahler differentials a flat module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

First let us recall one construction of the relative Kahler differentials. Let $k$ be a ring and $R$ a $k$-algebra. The relative Kahler differentials $\Omega_{R/k}$ are the $R$-module satisfying the following universal property:

> For any $R$-module $M$ and $k$-linear derivation $\delta:R\to M$ (an $R$-module homomorphism satisfying the Leibniz rule), there exists a universal derivation $d:R\to\Omega_{R/k}$ and a unique $R$-module homomorphism $\varphi:\Omega_{R/k}\to M$ such that $\varphi\circ d=\delta$.

You can use this universal property, along with some direct constructions and short exact sequences, to compute specific examples. Explicitly, suppose $R=k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]/(f_{1},\ldots,f_{s})$ is a $k$-algebra of finite type. Then one can show that $\Omega_{R/k}=(Rdx_{1}\oplus\cdots\oplus Rdx_{n})/(df_{1},\ldots,df_{s})$, and $d:R\to\Omega_{R/k}$ is given by $f\mapsto df$. Namely, the Kahler differentials are the cokernel of the Jacobian matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\end{bmatrix}:R^{s}\to R^{n}$.

I'm curious as to what hypotheses are known under which $\Omega_{R/k}$ is a flat $R$-module. For example, by our calculation above, $\Omega_{R/k}$ is free if $R$ is a polynomial $k$-algebra, and by [Proposition 3.9](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/chsmoothness.pdf#page=21) of these linked notes by Akhil Mathew, $\Omega_{R/k}$ is projective of rank $\dim R$ if and only if $R$ is regular; hence, $\Omega_{R/k}$ is flat in both of these circumstances.

My question: **What else can be said if we only need $\Omega_{R/k}$ to be a flat $R$-module? Even better, are there necessary and sufficient hypotheses on $R$ that guarantee flatness of $\Omega_{R/k}$, like is the case for projectiveness?**

Comment: A medium-size notational complaint: in algebraic geometry, $k$ is nearly universally a field (not an arbitrary ring). It would be better to say something like "Let $R$ be a ring and let $A$ be an $R$-algebra. The relative Kahler differentials $\Omega_{A/R}$ ...". This would reduce the opportunity for confusion.

Comment: @KReiser sure, but as fields are rings I am happy to have such answers. Unless there is a single characterization of the flatness of $\Omega_{R/k}$ that is the most general and subsumes all others I expect to get different answers depending on what hypotheses one takes on $k$, $R$, and $k\to R$.

Comment: You misunderstand: when you write $k$ people will assume it is a field **and ignore other possibilities** (or at least there's a good chance of that). So that portion of your question may not be addressed.

Answer (score 3):

If $ R $ is a finitely generated $ k $-algebra, hence Noetherian, then $ M = \Omega_{R/k} $ is a finitely presented $ R $-module. If in addition, if you assume that this is flat, then this gives you a flat coherent sheaf on $ \operatorname{spec} R $. It is a standard fact then, that this sheaf is now actually locally free. Let me try to recall the outline, but I'll add more details if necessary.

(1) Let $ P $ be a prime of $ R$. We can take elements $ \{ x_i \}_{i=1}^{d} $ of $ M $ which give a basis of $ M \otimes_R k(P) $. Nakayama's lemma and the fact that the sheaf is coherent imply that there is an $ f \notin P $ such that the above elements induce a surjection $$ R_f^{ \oplus d }\rightarrow M_f \rightarrow 0 $$

(2) Call the kernel above $ K $. Then $ K $ is a finitely generated $ R_f $-module by general nonsense (snake lemma).

(3) Because $ M_f $ is a flat $ R_f $-module, snake lemma again implies $$ 0 \rightarrow K \otimes_{R_f} k(P) \rightarrow k(P)^d \rightarrow M_f \otimes_{R_f} k(P) \rightarrow 0 $$ is exact. The surjection above has no kernel because $ \{ x_i \} $ was a basis. That is, $ K \otimes_{R_f} k(P) = 0 $.

(4) By exactly step (1) applied to $ K $ this time, there is a $ g \notin P $ such that $ K_g = 0 $.

So $ M_{fg} $ becomes locally free over $ R_{fg} $.

This shows that if you assume $ \Omega_{R/k} $ flat, $ R $ must be regular.

I don't know a reference but I have not seen this in Hartshorne. Maybe it's there in the book of Gortz and Wedhorn.

Comment: Good spot, +1. One slight issue: the OP is using the rather unusual convention that $k$ is just a ring, not necessarily a field. In general, $R$ finite presentation over $k$ implies $\Omega_{R/k}$ finitely presented over $R$, which combines with flatness to produce [locally free](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228441/finitely-presented-module-flat-implies-projective) so you can generalize the noetherian hypothesis if you want.

Comment: @CraniumClamp thanks. Can I ask questions to clarify? As I understand it, you're saying "if $R$ is regular, then $\Omega_{R/k}$ is flat" but this already known via the Mathew notes linked. Are you further claiming the converse; "if $\Omega_{R/k}$ is flat, then $R$ is regular"? Looking at the proof in Mathew's notes, I don't see how the projective hypothesis can be weakened to flat, so I'm afraid I don't understand this. Am I misunderstanding? If so, could you add more details to this answer? In particular, I don't follow (4) and I think the SES in (3) has a $k(P)^{d}$ that should be $k(P)$.

Comment: I proved the other way, didn't I? I showed that the Kahler differentials being flat implied them being locally free and now locally free implies that R is regular. See Hartshorne, chapter 2 section 8 for the last implication (which is iff, really). And thanks for catching the typo in (3).

Comment: In (4), the empty set can be taken to give you a basis and now just apply (1). That should be straightforward.